# If Russia drops a nuclear bomb, is it realistically possible to prevent neutralize it without getting serious damage?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, military, nuclear-weapons, war-crime

By "serious damage" I mean any kind of severe environmental damage and/or damage to the people health/life. I understand that there's a tiny probability for that to happen, but just in case, how would other countries prevent a disaster from happening?

Comment: Reading this question as written, the answer would be that undetonated nuclear ordnance is easy to neutralize. And detonated ordnance is just a blast radius. But either sounds like an engineering question more than a political one.

Comment: For detonated ordnance, you're probably looking for Nukemap [easy version](https://outrider.org/nuclear-weapons/interactive/bomb-blast?airburst=true&bomb=2&lat=50.4&location=Kyiv%2C%20Ukraine&long=30.5) or [full one](https://nuclearsecrecy.com/nukemap/).

Comment: What do you mean by preventing neutralization?

Comment: Not a political question.

Comment: @JamesK, I agree with that but I answered because I consider it important to inject some calm here. *Yes*, a tactical nuclear weapon would be bad. *No*, it isn't the end of the world.

Comment: A bomb is not 'dropped' as such, it is likely to be delivered in any number of ways, such as via cruise missile, or perhaps via ballistic delivery system. The best way to neutralise or otherwise avoid it carrying out its destructive mission, is to intercept it early on in the case of ballistic systems since the terminal phase is around Mach 21 and may use counter measure defeating maneuvers and rather difficult to destroy at that stage or anywhere along its flight path if a cruise missile (considerably slower). The atomic bomb equivalents of 1945 are about 15kt. Today that is much larger.

Comment: This question might be rephrased as something political. Right now it is a technical/engineering question. The answer to that is pretty much "no."  There is no known way of stopping nukes.

Answer (score 2):

The **explosion** of a *single* nuclear bomb does significant damage, but it isn't apocalyptic unless you stand below it. Nuclear bombs were dropped on Hiroshima and Nagasaki, today cities of several hundred thousand to a million inhabitants. There were plenty of surface tests, too.

On the other hand, *many, big* nuclear bombs would bring serious environmental effects, beyond the sum of the individual blasts. Scientists argue about the magnitude [nuclear winter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_winter) from the firestorms, and there would be few uncontaminated areas to flee to.

Casualties will depend on the yield (the kiloton-equivalent or megaton-equivalent in TNT), altitude, and very much on the location. A city is obviously worse than a rural area.

The amount of [fallout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fallout) depends on the yield and altitude, too. Some cleanup may be possible, similar to the activities after [Fukushima](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2019/mar/11/fukushima-toxic-soil-disaster-radioactive), or just an exclusion zone, as after [Chernobyl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_the_Chernobyl_and_Fukushima_nuclear_accidents). Consider the crew and cast of the John Wayne movie [downwind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downwinders#Health_effects_of_nuclear_testing) from the testing site.

Comment: the bombs dropped on japan were fission, modern "nukes" are fusion, which we could think of as "clean nukes" in terms of literal fallout.